# Prove that the following function is one-to-one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics

Define a function $g$ from the set of real numbers to $S$ by the following formula:

$$
g(x) = \frac12\biggl( \frac x{1+|x|} \biggr) + \frac12,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Prove that $g$ is a one-to-one correspondence. (It is possible to prove this statement either with calculus or without it.) What conclusion can you draw from this fact?

My question is that what is the conclusion we can draw after we decide that it is a one-to-one correspondence? I would prove its one-to-one correspondence through its graph, which is one-to-one in that no two $x$'s are mapped to the same $y$.

Comment: I've changed your image to a properly formatted math equation. Please use MathJax in the future instead of images of equations :)

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Simply calculate $g'$ it is positive. So $g$ continuous and strictly increasing so it is a bijection from its domain to its range. Remember that monotonous functions are always injective, continuity does the rest.

Comment: A graph is just a picture, an *illustration* of the math involved, not a proof of any kind.

Comment: What is $S$?  I'm not sure what conclusion you are supposed to draw about $g$ being 1-1 but on conclusion would be it prove $S$ (whatever $S$ is) is uncountable.  Maybe that is the conclusion you are expected to draw.

Comment: I think $S$ is the open interval $(0,1)$?  Is that correct?  If so, proving $g$ is one to one proves that $(0,1)$ is uncountable.  Or maybe we already *knew* that (by Cantors diagonal).  And this is to prove $\mathbb R$ is uncountable?

Answer (score 2):

That would mean that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\,\,g(x) \in \mathbb {R}$$ And more importantly:
$$ x = g^{-1}(g(x))$$
Meaning that the function is **invertible**.

You can find all the conclusions here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, one approach is to **compute the inverse**!

A graph of your function suggests that it passes the horizontal line test, which would mean it's invertible. One way to show this with calculus for your particular function is to take the derivative and show that it's always positive (i.e. the function is always increasing). This is a bit tough with the absolute value symbol involved, but you could analyze the function in two cases: one where $x \geq 0$ and one where $x < 0$.

Let's try to find the actual inverse for $x \geq 0$:

Over this domain, observe that $|x| = x$. So this restricted version of your function is

$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{x}{1+x}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}$$

For the parenthetical term, we can add then subtract $1$ to the numerator and rewrite as $1 - 1/(1+x)$:

$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\Big(1 - \frac{1}{1+x}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}$$

There are different ways to find the inverse of a function, but one method is to write the function as a composition of invertible functions, then compose their inverses in reverse order. Let us do that by examining what happens to the $x$ in the function written above. In particular, the applied operations are:

add one; reciprocal; negate; add one; halve; add half

Respectively, the inverses *in reverse order* are:

**subtract half; double; subtract one; negate; reciprocal; subtract one**

Let's now write this as a function:

$$x \mapsto x - \frac{1}{2} \mapsto 2x - 1 \mapsto 2x - 2 \mapsto -2x + 2 \mapsto \frac{1}{-2x + 2} \mapsto \frac{1}{-2x + 2} - 1$$

If we did this correctly, then it should appear like a reflection of the original function over the line $y = x$:

[image]

Indeed, we have found the inverse for your original function when $x \geq 0$.

I'll leave it to you to find the other piece, i.e., what to do when $x < 0$. Once you have both of those pieces, you can say that the function is one-to-one, i.e., invertible, i.e., has an inverse **because** it has the function you found *as its inverse*. This goes further than just proving an inverse must exist; it finds the function (piecewise) in closed form.

[**Here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y08q6zc12g) is a link to the Desmos graph depicted above.

Answer (score 0):

We only need to check that the condition $g(x)=g(y) \Rightarrow x=y$ holds true for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

For $x\ge0$ we have $$g(x) = \frac12\biggl( \frac x{1+x} \biggr) + \frac12\quad $$

So $$g(x)=g(y)\Rightarrow\\\frac12\biggl( \frac x{1+x} \biggr) + \frac12\quad=\frac12\biggl( \frac y{1+y} \biggr) + \frac12\quad\Rightarrow\\\frac x{1+x}=\frac y{1+y}\Rightarrow\\x+xy=y+xy\Rightarrow x=y$$

as desired.

Now we pm;y have to check the $x\lt0$ which is treated simialrly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what should we do
$$
g(\alpha)=g(\beta) \rightarrow \alpha=\beta
$$
$$
g(\alpha)=g(\beta) \rightarrow 
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha}{1+|\alpha|}\right)+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\beta}{1+|\beta|}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow \frac{\alpha}{1+|\alpha|}=\frac{\beta}{1+|\beta|}
$$
$$
\text{if } \alpha,\beta \geq 0 \rightarrow \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}=\frac{\beta}{1+\beta} \rightarrow \alpha=\beta
$$
Or
$$\text{if } \alpha, \beta < 0 \rightarrow \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\frac{\beta}{1-\beta} \rightarrow \alpha=\beta
$$
And we are done
We proved that the function is one-to-one!

Comment: Your argument is incomplete. There is a case missing.

Comment: What if $\alpha \ge 0$ but $\beta < 0$ Then you have $\frac \alpha{1-\alpha} = \frac \beta{1+\beta}$ and $\alpha -\alpha\beta = \beta + \alpha\beta$ and you are nowhere.

Comment: How is that possible?! If alpha is greater equal zero and beta is less than zero; how they could be equal???

Answer (score -1):

first recall $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ then 
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{2+2\sqrt{x^2}}+\frac{1}{2}$$
using the quotient rule we can find the derivative
$$g'(x)=\frac{2+2\sqrt{x^2}-x(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2}})}{(2+2\sqrt{x^2})^2}$$
multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2}$
$$g'(x)=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2}+2x^2-2x^2}{(2+2\sqrt{x^2})^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2}}{(2+2\sqrt{x^2})^2}=\frac{2|x|}{(2+2|x|)^2}$$
since $2|x|$ is greater than or equal to zero and $(2+2|x|)^2$ is greater than zero
then $g'(x)\geq0$ therefore $g(x)$ is one to one

Answer (score -1):

To prove that the function is one-to-one, we will have to prove that the function is **injective** $(g(x) = g(y))$ and **surjective** $(g(x) = y)$.

**Injectivity:**

Let x and y are a member of the function.
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{1+|x|} \right) + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{1+|y|} \right) + \frac{1}{2}
$$
By simplifying the above expression.
$$
\frac{x}{1+|x|} = \frac{y}{1+|y|}
$$
$$
x + x|y| = y + y|x|
$$
$$
x = y + y|x| -x|y|
$$
$$
x = y
$$
This shows that the function is an injective function.

Now we will prove that the function is a surjective function.

**Surjection:**

$$
y = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x}{1 + |x|} \right) + \frac{1}{2}
$$

$$
y - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x}{1+|x|} \right)
$$

$$
2y - 1 = \frac{x}{1+|x|}
$$

$$
(2y-1)(1+|x|) = x
$$
This shows that for every $y$ in the function, there exists an $x$ such that $g(x) = y$ which thus proves surjectivity for the function.

As a consequence of proving the injectivity and surjectivity of the function. We can now claim that the function is indeed one-to-one also. Hence proved.

Comment: 1) how does $x =y+ y|x| - x|y|$ mean that $x=y$?  2) $x =(2y-1)(1+|x|)$ does not mean an $x$ exists for every $y$.  We can not evaluate an $x$ from that as the LHS uses $x$ in its evaluation.

Comment: The function most certain is not surjective to $\mathbb R$.  $g(x) < 1$ It may be surjective to $S$ but it is not surjective to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @fleablood $x = y + y|x| - x|y|$ is $x = y$ as $y|x| and x|y|$ will cancel out. They are subtracting each other

Comment: Not if $x$ and $y$ are opposite signs they aren't.  $-3\cdot |5| - 5\cdot|-3| = 30$, not $0$.

Comment: Also your surjectivity still doesn't work.  Say $y = 0.7$ and so $x=(2y-1)(1+|x|)x$ so $x=.4(1+|x|)$.  What is $x$? You haven't solved it yet.  And what if $y=3$  so $x=5(1-|x|)$, what is $x$?